# Alert Controller is not displayed

Tags: ionic-framework

I am making an app with Ionic v6 .I set some localStorage items, when I'm trying to show an alert dialog, it doesn't work. But when i delete these items, the alert works correctly.
Any solution please ?!

This is the code

```
async presentAlert(){
    const alert =await this.alertController.create({
      header:'QR CODE',
      message: 'this is a message',
      buttons:['OK'],
    });
    await alert.present().then(()=>console.log("this works")).catch((err)=>console.error(err));
    
    let res= await alert.onDidDismiss();
    console.log(res);
  }
//html-content
// <ion-button (click)="presentAlert()">Click</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made an account to say that this also happens when you try to use ionic forms, so it's not just an issue with localstorage. This has been a headache for the last 2-3 days for me.

I moved my folder to the main app folder, fixed the routing issues that caused, and now it works fine. It must be a bug with the new Ionic version.